# How to get some class value in soup.findAll python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get some class values in one string

`<div class="col-md-9 bt-product-main-info"></div>`

I'm using

`soup.findAll(match_class("col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 bt-product-list"))`

But it's not working.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to target `<div>` which has class `col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 bt-product-list` ?

Comment: include url and give indication of expected result. You say one string? Do you mean string or list?

Answer (score 1):

Given the following HTML text:

```
text = """
<div class="col-md-9 bt-product-main-info">hij</div>
<div class="col-md-9">asdas</div>
<div class="bt-product-list">sdshij</div>
"""
```

If you want only records which has ***exact*** class name match, for example: `col-md-9 bt-product-main-info`, then do:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-9 bt-product-main-info')
```

The output will be:

```
[<div class="col-md-9 bt-product-main-info">hij</div>]
```

If you want records that match ***any*** of the following class names, for example: `col-md-9` or `bt-product-main-info`, then do:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_ = ['col-md-9', 'bt-product-main-info'])
```

The output will be:

```
[<div class="col-md-9 bt-product-main-info">hij</div>,
 <div class="col-md-9">asdas</div>]
```